# BigQuery SQL: Counting multiples of individual products (size and color)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking at a table of orders for an ecommerce website, trying to determine how many orders include multiples of the same product but *for different colors or different sizes*.

An example order would be one with 7 total SKUs. 1 is only 1 product/color/size, but the remaining 6 are all the same product/color, but 6 different sizes. That table would look like this.

```
order_id | product | sizes | colors
-----------------------------------
    1    |    A    |   6   |   1
    1    |    B    |   1   |   1
```

I'd like to just get a true/false on if the order has multiples in the size category or color category. So the resulting table would look like this.

```
order_id | multiple_sizes | multiple_colors
-------------------------------------------
    1    |      true      |      false
```

I tried using things like `IF(sizes > 1, true, false) mult_sizes, IF(colors > 1, true, false) mult_colors` and can get this to true/falses for each row, but I can't figure out how to group it based on the id alone and return a true if there's a true for *any* product.

I've tried similar things in the past using CASE WHEN, looked into using HAVING, and a number of other solutions but I can't seem to find a solution to this exact problem. Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I'd be happy to refer to something else if you can point me there. Thank you.

Comment: It seems very strange to me that an `orders` table would have the *number of different sizes* in the order, but not the actual sizes themselves.  That seems to be what your question is implying, though.

Comment: To clarify: this orders table is one I've built myself. Maybe there would be a better solution that would skip that step? Either way, I think I'm all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` logic and aggregation:

```
select order_id,
       (min(size) <> max(size)) as has_muliple_sizes,
       (min(color) <> max(color)) as has_muliple_colors
from t
group by order_id;
```

You can also use `count(distinct)`:

```
select order_id,
       (count(distinct size) > 1) as has_muliple_sizes,
       (count(distinct color) > 1) as has_muliple_colors
from t
group by order_id;
```

But I think `count(distinct)` might incur more overhead.

EDIT:

I may have misunderstood what the `size` and `color` columns represent.  If these are actually already the *number* of sizes and *number* of colors, then appropriate names would be `num_sizes` and `num_colors`.  More importantly, the SQL would just use `max()`:

```
select order_id,
       (max(size) > 1) as has_muliple_sizes,
       (max(color) > 1) as has_muliple_colors
from t
group by order_id;
```

Comment: Sorry never came back to this but your solution did work, thank you!